# Using ebays AddMemberMessageAAQToPartner call with a custom subject

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I'm trying to send a message to the buyer of an item in eBay, all works fine except i cant get a customized subject line working.

This is the reference to the api **[here](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/AddMemberMessageAAQToPartner.html)**

Regardless of what I put in the subject the buyer is always getting a standardized eBay subject.

I know I can use `SetMessagePreferences` to set various hardwired subjects, though this approach is not optimal, as I would like to put the order number and the line item id in the subject, this does not seem to be possible.

The following is an example using the .net API, though this question should be valid for any platform:

```
   var apiCall = new AddMemberMessageAAQToPartnerCall(apiContext)
        {
           ItemID = salesSourceId, 
           MemberMessage = new MemberMessageType
              {
                 MessageType = MessageTypeCodeType.ContactEbayMember,
                 Body = messageBody, 
                 Subject = subject, 
                 EmailCopyToSender = true,
                 QuestionType = QuestionTypeCodeType.General, 
                 RecipientID = new StringCollection
                    {
                       ebayUserId
                    }, 
              }
        };
```

I've tried all possible `MessageTypeCodeType`, and `QuestionTypeCodeType` configuration though nothing seems to work.

So I'm wondering if the subject is valid, the API doesn't make any mention of this, and gives you the ability to use the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this question type. It works for me.

```
QuestionType = 'CustomizedSubject'
```